# Query Slowness With records in millions

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, query-optimization, database-performance

I have below query which deals with 10 million records in each ent_data and ent_details tables in Oracle DB.

```
select val1.type,count(val1.type) 
  from ent_data val1 
       inner join ent_details az 
           ON val1.ENT_ID=az.ent_id 
          and val1.ENT_TYPE=az.ent_type 
          and val1.user_key=87
 group by val1.type;


----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Operation                            | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   HASH GROUP BY                      |                             |     3 |   126 |       |   135K  (1)| 00:27:10 |
    FILTER                            |                             |       |       |       |            |          |
     HASH JOIN                        |                             |    10M|   413M|   305M|   134K  (1)| 00:26:56 |
      TABLE ACCESS FULL               | ent_details                 |    10M|   187M|       | 13116   (2)| 00:02:38 |
      TABLE ACCESS FULL               | ent_data                    |    10M|   226M|       | 89074   (1)| 00:17:49 |
```

Executing above query takes around 27 seconds time for execution on SQL Developer but as the fetched data is used for display on UI 27 seconds is something I can't live with.

I have indexes on Category, ENT_ID and ent_type column of ent_data table. Also I have indexes on ent_id and ent_type column of ent_details table.

Will appreciate any guidance on how the query performance can be improved.

Comment: You could try having the following indexes: on `ent_data`, a multi-column index on `(ent_id, ent_type, user_key, val1)` and on `ent_details`, a multi-column index on `(ent_id, ent_type)`. What are the primary keys of both tables? Also, is there a foreign key between ent_details and ent_data?

Comment: You could also try moving the `and val1.user_key = 87` from the join condition to the where clause; that may encourage the filter to be done before the join rather than afterwards - especially if you create that multi-column index that I suggested on ent_data.

Comment: @Boneist there is already a multi column index on (ent_id, ent_type) for both ent_details and ent_data tables. Will it make sense to create another index including user_key for ent_data table ?

Comment: Also there is no foreign key relation between these two tables.

Comment: If you create the index on all four columns (ent_id, ent_type, user_key, type\*), that should allow the query to use an index rather than needing to query the whole table. (\*not val1 as I mistyped above!)

Comment: i can try that..but ent_data table have 9 indexes already for varying columns/multii columns used for this/other use cases. Was wondering if adding another index might have any downside ?

Comment: inserts/updates/deletes could be slower. But you could potentially drop some of the other indexes if their columns are in the leading edge of the new index.

Comment: @Boneist I have introduced an Index based on columns mentioned but still dont see any improvement. I have rebuild the index and even tried to supply index as hint but of no help ..

Comment: Did you try moving `val1.user_key=87` out of the join and putting it as a predicate?

Comment: How many ent_data rows have user_key=87?

Comment: ent_data has around 99% of data mapped to user_key 87. user_key is nothing but the account key in our terminology. In one of customer scenario 99% of data(almost 10 million) has been mapped to this particular account which is causing issue with this query. I tried moving the user_key as predicate but it didn't help much given the amount of data associated with this account 87.

Comment: OK - that explains why an index on `user_key` is not present (it wouldn't help anyway, if 99% of the data is mapped to just one value). Otherwise the plan seems as efficient as it can be. You say the query is "slow" but in fact it isn't - it is processing 100 trillion combinations (10 million times 10 million) in 27 seconds. "It takes a long time" ("long" is subjective of course) is not the same as "it is slow." It is just processing a very, very large (huge, gigantic) amount of data.

Comment: If this is a query that you use often (or that other queries depend on), you may want to consider creating a fast refreshable materialized view - assuming the frequency of transactions is not too high. MV's come with their own overhead (just like indexes do), but they may help exactly in your type of situations.

Comment: @mathguy frequency of transaction can be high..its important that solution should be handle multiple concurrent user access.